# SQL Update with CTEs not updating records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to update a set of records that are duplicates in three particular columns. The reason for this update is that there is a conflict when trying to insert this data into an updated database schema. The conflict is caused by a new constraint that has been added on `DM_ID`, `DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID`, and `DMC_TYPE`. I need to adjust the `DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID` column to either 1, 3, or 5 based on the row number to get around this. A sample of the duplicate data looks as such. Notice that the first three columns are the same.

```
+--------+--------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| DM_ID  | DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID | DMC_TYPE | DMC_PATH                             |
+--------+--------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| 314457 | 1                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\CD\1965\19651227\7897-0.tif |
| 314457 | 1                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\DR\640\0001_640_0001.tif    |
| 314458 | 1                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\CD\1965\19651227\7898-0.tif |
| 314458 | 1                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\TD\640\0002_640_0001.tif    |
| 314460 | 1                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\CD\1965\19651227\7900-0.tif |
| 314460 | 1                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\ZZ\640\0003_640_0003.tif    |
| 314461 | 1                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\CD\1965\19651227\7901-0.tif |
| 314461 | 1                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\ED\6501\03_0001.tif         |
| 314461 | 1                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\ZZ\640\0004_640_0004.tif    |
+--------+--------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

This is the desired output to get around the constraint issue:

```
+--------+--------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| DM_ID  | DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID | DMC_TYPE | DMC_PATH                             |
+--------+--------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| 314457 | 1                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\CD\1965\19651227\7897-0.tif |
| 314457 | 3                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\DR\640\0001_640_0001.tif    |
| 314458 | 1                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\CD\1965\19651227\7898-0.tif |
| 314458 | 3                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\TD\640\0002_640_0001.tif    |
| 314460 | 1                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\CD\1965\19651227\7900-0.tif |
| 314460 | 3                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\ZZ\640\0003_640_0003.tif    |
| 314461 | 1                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\CD\1965\19651227\7901-0.tif |
| 314461 | 3                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\ED\6501\03_0001.tif         |
| 314461 | 5                  | TIF      | \\DOCIMG\ZZ\640\0004_640_0004.tif    |
+--------+--------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

The script I have developed is as such:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT -- Grab the documents that have a duplicate.
    DM_ID
    ,DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID
    ,DMC_TYPE
    ,COUNT(*) 'COUNT'
FROM
    [DM_CONTENT]
GROUP BY
    DM_ID
    ,DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID
    ,DMC_TYPE
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1),
CTE2 AS
(SELECT -- Designate the row number for the duplicate documents.
    DMC.*
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DMC.DM_ID, DMC.DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID, DMC.DMC_TYPE ORDER BY DMC.DMC_PATH) AS 'ROWNUM'
FROM
    [DM_CONTENT] DMC
    JOIN CTE
        ON DMC.DM_ID = CTE.DM_ID),
CTE3 AS
(SELECT -- Set the new document type ID based on the row number.
    *
    ,CASE
        WHEN ROWNUM = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN ROWNUM = 2
            THEN 3
        WHEN ROWNUM = 3
            THEN 5
        END AS 'DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID_NEW'
FROM
    CTE2)
UPDATE -- Update the records.
    DMC
SET
    DMC.DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID = CTE3.DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID_NEW
FROM
    [DM_CONTENT] DMC
    JOIN CTE3
        ON DMC.DM_ID = CTE3.DM_ID
```

Now when I execute the script, it says that the appropriate rows have been affected. However, when I check the `[DM_CONTENT]` table, the `DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID` actually hasn't been updated and still remains at a value of `1`. If I `SELECT` from `CTE3`, the `DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID_NEW`, is the appropriate new ID. My logic seems to be sound, but I cannot figure out what mistake I am making. Does anyone have any insight? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to update the same table from which you are selecting, and this could be the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems much simpler to write as:

```
WITH toupdate AS (
      SELECT DMC.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DMC.DM_ID, DMC.DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID, DMC.DMC_TYPE
                               ORDER BY DMC.DMC_PATH) AS ROWNUM
      FROM DM_CONTENT DMC
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID = (CASE ROWNUM WHEN 2 THEN 3 WHEN 3 THEN 5 END)
    WHERE ROWNUM > 1;
```

Now, I find it suspicious that your `join` conditions are only on `DM_ID`.  I think the problem is that you are getting multiple matches between the CTE and your table.  An arbitrary match is used for the update -- and that happens to be the first one encountered (hence a value of 1).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
UPDATE CTE3
SET DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID = DM_CONTENT_TYPE_ID_NEW
```

instead of what you're currently doing.

Updating from a CTE works a little different that regular table joins.

Answer (score 1):

Should work with any no. of duplicates. Try this way

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY dm_id, dm_content_type_id, dmc_type 
                    ORDER BY DMC_PATH)     AS Rn, 
                * 
         FROM   dm_content) 
UPDATE cte 
SET    dm_content_type_id = rn + (rn -1)
```